# How to validate phone number using Yup but is not required?

Tags: validation, phone-number, yup

I am able to validate if what is typed a phone number using this regexp but it is requiring a phone number to be entered in the input field. I am trying to make phone number optional. When I remove .matches phoneRegExp, it works without being required. I believe it has something to do with the regexp that makes the field turn into required. But I am not sure. Should I do it a different way? thanks

```
        const phoneRegExp = /^((\\+[1-9]{1,4}[ \\-]*)|(\\([0-9]{2,3}\\)[ \\-]*)|([0-9]{2,4})[ \\-]*)*?[0-9]{3,4}?[ \\-]*[0-9]{3,4}?$/;

const signUpSchema = yup.object().shape({
  username: yup
    .string()
    .min(4, "Need at least 4 characters.")
    .required("Username is required"),
  firstName: yup
    .string()
    .min(2, "Need at least 2 characters.")
    .required("First name is required"),
  lastName: yup
    .string()
    .min(2, "Need at least 2 characters")
    .required("Last name is required"),
  email: yup
    .string()
    .email()
    .required("Email is required"),
  phoneNumber: yup.string()
    .matches(phoneRegExp, "Phone number is not valid")
    .notRequired(),
  password: yup
    .string()
    .min(6, "Password must be at least 6 characters.")
    .required("Password is required"),
  instructorOrClient: yup
    .string()
    .matches(/(instructor|client)/, "Either instructor or client.")
    .required("Please select instructor or client."),
});
```

Comment: If you are still looking for an answer or better approach, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65373151/13965360 is one of the best ways that works even in RHF v7 like a charm

Answer (score 22):

Add `excludeEmptyString:true` to matches. need to be an object.

```
{
message:"Phone not valid",
excludeEmptyString:true
}
```

Example

```
  const PHONE_NO_REGEX = /^[0-9\- ]{8,14}$/
        const signUpSchema = yup.object().shape({
        ...
        phoneNumber: yup.string()
            .matches(PHONE_NO_REGEX, phoneNumber:yup.string().matches(PHONE_NO_REGEX,{message:"not valid phone no",excludeEmptyString:true}))
          
        ...
        });
```

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: I think `phoneNumber` is redundant

Comment: Should be `.matches(PHONE_NO_REGEX, {message:"not valid phone no",excludeEmptyString:true})`

Answer (score 1):

You should do `.nullable()`:

```
const signUpSchema = yup.object().shape({
...
phoneNumber: yup.string()
    .matches(phoneRegExp, "Phone number is not valid")
    .nullable(),
...
});
```

You can read more about this on [docs](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixednullableisnullable-boolean--true-schema).

Comment: `''` is not the same as `null`

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your regex which will support both phone numbers or the empty string

To match pattern or an empty string, use

```
^$|phoneRegx
```

Explanation

- ^ and $ are the beginning and end of the string anchors respectively.
  | is used to denote alternates, e.g. this|that.

`const phoneRegExp =/^$| ^((\\+[1-9]{1,4}[ \\-]*)|(\\([0-9]{2,3}\\)[ \\-]*)|([0-9]{2,4})[ \\-]*)*?[0-9]{3,4}?[ \\-]*[0-9]{3,4}?$/`

```
phoneNumber: yup.string().matches(phoneRegExp, "Phone number is not valid"),
```