# Yup validation check if not empty

Tags: yup

```js
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    newPassword: Yup.string().min(8, 'Password must be at least 8 characters');
});
```

I want to validation check only if newPassword field is not empty.
How could I do?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are different approach on solving this problem.

Using **test**

```js
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    newPassword: Yup.string().test(
        'empty-check',
        'Password must be at least 8 characters',
         password => password.length == 0
    });
```

Using **when**

> Using the "when" method doesn't work anymore as it is a cyclic dependency [copied from the comment section]

```js
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    newPassword: Yup.string().when('newPassword',{
        is:(password) => password.length > 0
        then: Yup.string().min(8, 'Password must be at least 8 characters');
    });
```

Comment: Using "when" method doesn't work anymore as it is a cyclic dependency

Comment: @unlimittt maybe you know alternative?

Comment: The right alternative is to use `.test`. You will have access to the original value there

Answer (score 13):

Alternative using **test**:

```js
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    newPassword: Yup.string().test(
        'empty-or-8-characters-check',
        'Password must be at least 8 characters',
        password => !password || password.length >= 8,
    ),
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Alternative using `trim()`

```js
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    newPassword: Yup.string().trim().required("Password must be at least 8 characters"),
  });
```

Answer (score 7):

The way I solved this for myself was to first add .nullable() and then .transform() empty string into a null.

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    newPassword: Yup
        .string()
        .nullable()
        .transform((v, o) => (o === '' ? null : v))
        .min(8, 'Password must be at least 8 characters')
});
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a way of using `.when()` and not generating a cyclic dependency like the accepted answer, `.shape()` accepts an exhaustive list of dependencies as last argument, that resolves the cyclic conflict, the secret is using the same key twice https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/176#issuecomment-369925782

```js
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    newPassword: Yup.string().test(
        'empty-or-8-characters-check',
        'Password must be at least 8 characters',
        password => !password || password.length >= 8,
    ),
}, [["newPassword","newPassword"]]);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer and linking to the issue. There seems to be nothing in the documentation about this `noSortEdges` besides listing the parameter's existence: https://github.com/jquense/yup#objectshapefields-object-nosortedges-arraystring-string-schema Seems there's an open issue here around the documentation: https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/1339

Comment: This must be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is:

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    newPassword: Yup
     .string()
     .matches(/^\w{8}/, "Password must be at least 8 characters")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative that won't allow 8 empty characters.

```js
const notEmpty = Yup.string()
  .ensure() // Transforms undefined and null values to an empty string.
  .test('Only Empty?', 'Cannot be only empty characters', (value) => {
    const isValid = value.split(' ').join('').length !== 0;

    return isValid;
  });

const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    newPassword: notEmpty.min(8, 'Password must be at least 8 characters');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the Yup function `nullable()` so it is only validated with the next functions if it not null:

```
kmBegin: Yup.number().nullable().positive().integer(),
parcelTotal: Yup.number().positive().integer(),
timeBegin: Yup.date(),
timeEnd: Yup.date().nullable(),
```