# Nullable string with min/max range using Yup validation

Tags: javascript, yup

I have found that `yup` ignores the `nullable` field when there is a min/max value added.

```
myValue: string().nullable().min(10, "This value must be minimum of 10 characters.")`.
```

There was an [issue](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/338) that was closed on the repo without any solution given.

Is this expected behaviour, and if so are there any workarounds? I could check the length of the value without using yup and raise an error, however would prefer to keep it all within the yup schema validation.

Answer (score 6):

Had this exact issue today and was surprised to not see more discussion on it.

Based on Raz's answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70871588/18083192), I believe this happens because an empty string is not treated as null in yup, and so the min / max validation runs.

I'd suggest transforming the empty string to null as part of the validation as below:

```
myValue: string().nullable().transform((o, c) => o === "" ? null : c).min(10, "This value must be minimum of 10 characters.").
```